# Interval count down timer doesn't work

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

I am trying to make an interval count down timer app. I already made a normal timer which counts down 3 minutes - you can change the time of course - but I would like to have a count down timer which counts down 20 seconds, and as soon as they are over 10, more should start. I seriously don't know how to make it, that's why I need some help. If anyone could help me to fix it, I would be very thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code, check it out:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnStart, btnStop;
    TextView textViewTime;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        textViewTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        textViewTime.setText("00:03:00");
        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000,1000);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTime.setText("Completed.");
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            textViewTime.setText(hms);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, as soon as 00:00 is reached, 10 more seconds should count down automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is use `Threads`. Here's an example of how it will work. Add this Thread in your method:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
@Override // only add this if required
public void run(){
       try{
              // code here
              Thread.sleep(AmountOfTimeInMilliSeconds);
        catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
});
thread.start();
```

If you want to loop this, simply add a while(true) statement and it will continue to loop.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I should paste that in ? :)

Comment: Create the thread outside of your method (like in the class). Then whenever you want to start (onClickEvent) put this thread.start(); when you want to stop put this thread.stop. Just copy paste all that above (Except the last thread.start()) and paste it in the class.

Comment: You mean the onTick Method ?

Comment: works perfectly fine, but when the first 20 seconds are over and the sleep starts the numbers in the textViewTime aren´t 00:00:00, instead they are 00:00:01,  do you know how to solve that ? :)

Comment: i.e if you want 20 seconds which is 20,000 milliseconds, and it's starting from 1, simply do 21 seconds which 21,000 milliseconds. (but it will 20 seconds).

Comment: This is a countown timer :D--It doesn´t start at 00:00:00, it starts  at 00:00:20. But, when the Method onFinish with the sleep Thread starts(so when 20 seconds are over) the timer Displays 00:00:01 instead of 00:00:00. When the 15 seconds are over the timer starts again at 00:00:20.    Do you understand what I mean ? :)

Comment: Then whatever value you give it i.e 20 seconds to start with, then start it on 21 seconds. What do you mean the timer starts again? If you don't want it to start use `thread.stop();` method. Make sure when you declare the thread, it is accessible by all classes, if not make it `volatile`

Comment: No no, it should start again when the timer end the sleep thread are over. But as soon as the actual timer is over the texview which Displays the numbers is 00:00:01 and not 00:00:00. The 30 seconds Count down perfectly fine, but when the sleep starts the displayed time is 00:00:00. So what I want to tell you is, that the sleep doesn´t start at 00:00:00.